# is it possible to call a method when application is not running in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I need to register local notification after every 24 hours . i need to acheive this even if the app is not in running state
can i use ios7 background fetch for this?
I have tried using background fetch but this is working only when app is in background state

Answer (score 0):

I suggest sticking with UILocalNotification since you know the interval for which you need to deliver the notifications. Your app does not need to be running to deliver the notifications, the operating system handles that. Furthermore, the operating system allows you to schedule a maximum of 64 notifications at a time, which would translate to 64 days worth of notifications in your case. On app launch, you should reschedule notifications for the next 64 days.

More info here: [UILocalNotification Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: say i have 10 notification to be scheduled daily then i can schedule notification for 6 days on application launch. And what if the application is not launched for next 6 days how can i schedule notification for the 7th day is it possible?

Comment: In that case your are left with background fetch option.